# Select from 3 tables SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have similar table structure like it's shown below:

Table 1 - Category c

```
cat_id | name
1        Music
2        Books
```

Table 2 - Unknown u

```
unk_id | eng_id_fk | progress 
1          1          0
2          2          0
3          3          1
4          4          0
5          5          1
6          6          0
7          7          1
```

Table 3 - eng e

```
e_id | e_name   | category_id_fk
1      example1       1
2      example2       1
3      example3       1
4      example4       2
5      example5       2
6      example6       1
7      example7       1
```

I want to have select statement with output:

```
c.cat_id | c.name | count(u.unk_id) where u.eng_id_fk = e.e_id | count(u.unk_id where progress>0)
1.         Music        5                                              2     
2.         Books        2                                              1
```

I've tried to do it, and I have something like this:

```
 SELECT c.cat_id,c.name,count(u.unk_id) AS counts FROM category c, eng e, unknown u  WHERE e.e_id= u.ENG_ID_FK  AND e.category_id_fk=c.cat_id group by c.name order by c.cat_id;
```

So I have almost everything. I just don't know how cat I get count of rows unk_id where progress>0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I just needed to know how to specify condition in count() to get count of unknown_id where progress>0.

```
select c.cat_id, c.name, count(u.unk_id) AS COUNTS,
count(case when u.progress>0 then 1 else null end) AS PROGRESS
FROM category c, eng e, unknown u 
WHERE e.e_id=u.eng_id_fk AND e.category_id_fk = c.cat_id
group by c.name order by c.cat_id;
```